# Intellij, empty project. Lombok issues

Tags: java, maven, lombok

I have an empty Intellij project with two modules. When I install the lombok plugin and add the dependency to maven my module disappear. The .iml file is also missing. I think that's the reason, why it won't show up in Intellij anymore. Could someone please help me or tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the intellij window. Are the modules deleted or just hidden?

Comment: The Lombok plugin has nothing to do with your module structure.

Comment: @mahfujasif they are just hidden. The .iml file is missing.

Comment: @Makoto I know but why does it happen, when I add it? Maybe the maven dependency is the reason why?!

Comment: Unless you're stomping over a lot of modules in your Maven description, *that* shouldn't impact your module structure either.  IntelliJ does rely on Maven for module structure if it's present.  Does the issue go away if you remove the dependency?

Comment: No, I removed the dependency and now my other module is gone. Also the rest of the project is messed up and I think I will just clone it from my github again and try if it works then